# Not able to get the average and standard deviation by multiple rows in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mean, standard-deviation

```
root
 |-- cores: long (nullable = true)
 |-- time0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time2: double (nullable = true)

+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|cores|time0             |time1             |time2            |
+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|1    |26.362340927124023|25.891045093536377|26.19786810874939|
|2    |28.445404767990112|32.81148290634155 |30.37511706352234|
|4    |29.17068886756897 |28.47817611694336 |29.78126311302185|
+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

I want the resultant dataframe which includes me the mean and the std-deviation column as well.

```
df_mean_stddev = df_cores.withColumn('*', F.mean(array(df_cores.columns[1:])).alias('mean'))
.withColumn(stddev(array(df_cores.columns[1:])).alias('stddev'))
df_mean_stddev.printSchema()

df_cores.show(truncate=False)
```

I Tried the above, but i am getting the error. None of the example seems to be working correctly for me, referred multiple aggregation by row. I am new to PySpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.mean.html) and [stddev](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.stddev.html) can caluclate the mean and standard deviation of columns but these functions do not work for rows.

One approach to calculate the values per row would be to create an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) and then use the standard Python ways. But as there are only three columns in the dataset, the formulas can also be written directly in SQL:

```python
df.withColumn("mean", F.expr("(time0 + time1 + time2)/3")) \
    .withColumn("stddev", F.expr("sqrt((pow((time0-mean),2)+pow((time1-mean),2)+pow((time2-mean),2))/2)")) \
    .show()
```

prints

```python
+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|cores|             time0|             time1|            time2|              mean|             stddev|
+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|    1|26.362340927124023|25.891045093536377|26.19786810874939|26.150418043136597|0.23920403891711864|
|    2|28.445404767990112| 32.81148290634155|30.37511706352234|30.544001579284668| 2.1879330570873967|
|    4| 29.17068886756897| 28.47817611694336|29.78126311302185|29.143376032511394| 0.6519727164969239|
+-----+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```